# Upload multiple images via REST api in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ionic3

I have requirement where app has to upload 100+ images via REST. I have created a custom background queue. When app goes to background iOS suspends the app and uploading stop. I have tried using background mode and scheduling a background task to extend the time but iOS doesn’t extend it. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to keep the app alive in this case.  It's not possible to continue long-running operations like this in the background.

Comment: You have ~30 seconds of background task time.

Comment: Suppose you have 100 pics to upload. Try keeping the local state of uploaded ones. You can have a callback when the application goes background or comes back up. Start syncing the left-out uploads when the app opens again.

Comment: Do not use background queue. Use background `URLSessionConfiguration`. That way, uploads will proceed even when the user leaves your app to go do something else (but not if the user force-quits it). See [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/), which outlines many of the moving parts. Background uploads work basically the same (though not discussed in that particular document). Bottom line, different use of the word “background” and don’t conflate them.